# How could you get the row-wise frequency of equivalent combinations of elements (partitioned as fixed sets of columns) in a table?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

How could you get the row-wise frequency of equivalent combinations of elements (partitioned as fixed sets of columns) in a table?

Say I have a table with rows of the form:

```
[id1, a1, b1, c1, d1, e1, f1]
[id2, a2, b2, c2, d2, e2, f2]
[id3, a3, b3, c3, d3, e3, f3]
...
```

where, splitting the a-c and d-f columns into *sets* eg.

```
set11={a1, b1, c1}
set12={d1, e1, f1}
Letting setyz denote the zth set in the yth row
```

, there may be multiple (or no) rows where `setR1` = `setR2` (meaning that they contain the same elements not necessarily in same order) and multiple rows may have the same two sets (also not necessarily in the same order as their equivalent sets in other rows).

How would I get the frequency of *set matches* for each row? Eg.

```
[id1, a1,      b1,      c1,      d1(=a1), e1(=b1), f1(=c1)]
[id2, a2,      b2,      c2,      d2(=a2), e2(=b2), f2(=c2)]
[id3, a3(=a2), b3(=b2), c3(=c2), d3(=c2), e3(=b2), f3(=a2)]
[id4, a4(=c2), b4(=b2), c4(=a2), d4(=c2), e4(=b2), f4(=a2)]

gets turned into / results in table like

[a1, b1, c1, d1, e1, f1, 1]
[a2, b2, c2, d2, e2, f2, 3]
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using a couple [common table expressions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175972.aspx) and [**`cross apply()`**](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175156(v=sql.105).aspx) to unpivot the data:

```
;with cte as ( /* unpivot */
  select t.*, x, y
  from t
    cross apply (values (a,d),(b,e),(c,f)) v (x,y)
)
, match as ( /* set matching */
  select l.id as lid, r.id as rid, l.a, l.b, l.c, l.d, l.e, l.f
  from cte l
    left join cte r
      on l.x = r.y
  group by l.id, r.id, l.a, l.b, l.c, l.d, l.e, l.f
  having count(*) = 3 /* 3 is the number of elements in the sets */
)
/* return first instance of a set's order along with match count */ 
select a, b, c, d, e, f, count(rid) as [match_count]
from match m
where not exists (
  select 1
  from match i
  where i.lid = m.lid
    and i.rid < i.lid
  )
group by a, b, c, d, e, f
```

rextester demo: http://rextester.com/FUVAS63883

returns:

```
+----+----+----+----+----+----+-------------+
| a  | b  | c  | d  | e  | f  | match_count |
+----+----+----+----+----+----+-------------+
| a1 | b1 | c1 | a1 | b1 | c1 |           1 |
| a2 | b2 | c2 | a2 | b2 | c2 |           3 |
| a5 | b5 | c5 | d5 | e5 | f5 |           0 |
+----+----+----+----+----+----+-------------+
```

from this test setup:

```
create table t (id int, a char(2), b char(2), c char(2), d char(2), e char(2), f char(2))
insert into t values 
 (1,'a1','b1','c1','a1','b1','c1')
,(2,'a2','b2','c2','a2','b2','c2')
,(3,'a2','b2','c2','c2','b2','a2')
,(4,'c2','b2','a2','c2','b2','a2')
,(5,'a5','b5','c5','d5','e5','f5');
```